# Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' im trying to create a listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm new in android studio and I'm trying to create a fragment with a list and show it on a drawer class that I use to show all my fragments, I already read a lot of post but I can't find the answer I'm looking for, let me paste you my code so you can check it.

layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment class code:

```
public class FragmentoPrincipalChofer extends ListFragment {
    private List<ParseObject> mViaje;
    private ListView mLista;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_principal_chofer, container, false);
        mLista = (ListView)x.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        String[] nombres= new String[2];
        nombres[0]="gaston";
        nombres[1]="gaston";
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nombres);
        mLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return x;

    }
```

drawer class code:

```
public class DrawerPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentoPrincipalUsuario.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_principal);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //cargar fragment principal usuario

    FragmentoPrincipalChofer fragmento=(FragmentoPrincipalChofer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmento");
    if (fragmento==null){
        fragmento=new FragmentoPrincipalChofer();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content,fragmento,"fragmento");
        transaction.commit();

    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) so...

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, **your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"** (or list if it's in code)

Change the `ListView` XML to the following

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

And your reference to it as such

```
mLista = (ListView)x.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks a lot for your anwer now its working, but i have one problem, the list its overlapping the the title bar, do you know how can i change that? thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide a picture? You'd probably be better off asking this in a separate question though

Comment: No problem! Consider marking this answer as correct to help other people find it in the future!